# no caching file for writing last update content into file with Symfony into controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig, file-put-contents

I would like to create a file based on template Twig (and one parameter).

My file generated correctly with replace variable with my data. But if I change data my controller symfony generated always the same file with the same content. 
My varDumper content (the text/plain character represent file) is good. It's change always with change variable content. But the writing file always generate the same content...

PHP seems do not caching with fwrite ou file_put_contents function but my content never change. I also disable caching for twigEngine but same result.

Can you help me to writing file with good last content.

All code is in a controller symfony. I keep comment code for your understanding all my test :

```
    public function createEntityAction()
    {

        $rootDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
        $templateDir = $rootDir . '/../src/CmsBundle/Resources/views/Entity/templateFile/';
        $filename = 'test.php';
        $pathFile = $templateDir . $filename;

        $twigEngine = $this->get('twig');
        $twigEngine->setCache(false);
        $twigEngine->disableAutoReload();

//        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($templateDir);
//        $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
//            'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
//            'cache' => false,
//        ]);

        $baseTemplate = $twigEngine->loadTemplate('@Cms/Entity/templateFile/baseEntity.html.twig');

        $script = $baseTemplate->render(['slug' => 'product-333']);

        \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump($script);

        if (file_exists($pathFile))
        {
            clearstatcache(true);
            $ret = unlink($pathFile);
            \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump($ret);
        }

        $file = fopen($pathFile, 'w+');
        fwrite($file, $script);
        fclose($file);

//        file_put_contents($pathFile, $script);

        return $this->render('@Cms/Entity/create.html.twig', []);
    }
```

*The final file content is always the same if I change the "slug" variable.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing a variable in your controller. There should be something like this `createEntityAction($slug)`, then this line should be `$baseTemplate->render(['slug' => $slug)`; Right now it is doing exactly what you are telling it, you have a hard  coded string for the slug...

If you post your controller definition it would help (annotations or yaml)